# MySQL: Count how many times value in one column appears in another column

Tags: mysql, sql

In my Database I have a user table which has one column with the User_ID and anther column with the path of the whole "tree".

| user_id | promoter_path |
| --- | --- |
| 1200 | /200/840/780/1200 |
| 1785 | /14/74/787/898/1047/1687/1785 |
| 2687 | /2687 |
| ... | ... |
| 7847 | /200/840/780/**1200**/5870/7847 |
| ... | ... |

If I want to know how many children the user_id 1200 has I do:

```
select 
max(user_id) as name, 
count(*) as c
FROM users 
where promoter_path like '%1200%'
```

and I get

| name | c |
| --- | --- |
| 1200 | 2 |

So far it's easy.
But how can I do if I want a list for all ids?
Like

| name | c |
| --- | --- |
| 1200 | 2 |
| 1785 | 1 |
| 5550 | 5 |
| 10287 | 1 |
| --- | --- |

```
select max(u.user_id) as name,
       (
        select count(*) from users as u1 where promoter_path like u.user_id
       ) as c
from users as u
```

but this won't work.

Can you please help me?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: You're right, I'm sorry. 
It's mySQL. I edited the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lose the `max`. You also want to add `%` around the user_id in `like`:

```
select u.user_id as name,
       (
        select count(*) from users where promoter_path like concat('%', u.user_id, '%')
       ) as c
from users as u
```

By the way OP, are you sure it shouldn't be:

```
select u.user_id as name,
       (
        select count(*) from users
        where promoter_path like concat('%/', u.user_id, '/%')
        or promoter_path like concat('%/', u.user_id)
       ) as c
from users as u
```

Because `'/11200/something' like '%1200%'` evaluates as true...

Comment: Thank you. One question: Since this is very slow, do you know if there is a faster (and smarter) way to do it?

Comment: @FabioManniti you're welcome.
Honestly I'd take a look at how to store hierarchies in a relational database, there are better ways to do it than using strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    u1.id, COUNT(u2.id)
FROM users u1 LEFT JOIN users u2
ON
    u2.promoter_path LIKE concat('%/', u1.id, '/%') 
    OR pomoter_path like concat('%/', u.user_id) 
GROUP BY
    u1.id;
```

What this does, is:

1. pairs each user with users whose `promoter_path` includes their id (this could be event the same user)
2. counts how many users were paired with each user

the `LEFT JOIN` is important, so we get users with no matches as well.

Comment: I have tried this but it keeps running without any result. So far I kept it for 33 minutes and it was still running

Comment: @FabioManniti yeah, I wrote `'%'` instead of `'%/'` etc, so it just kept matching ids with parts of numbers, should work now (thing that @Zakaria pointed out in their answer)